# SQL Server Specific Date Format DD MM YYYY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I have a date formatting requirement that initially looked straightforward, but is proving to be a pain.  I'm using SQL Server 2012, but need to support 2008.

Looking at reference (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) I can use CONVERT to format a datetime as a string in a lot of different formats, but I can't seem to get DD MM YYYY without workarounds.  Is there a code that's not included on that reference that I'm missing somewhere?

Workarounds I can see are as follows, but I'm obviously not keen to use these if there's a sensible way to do it with T-SQL.

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103), '/',' ')
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(dd, GETDATE())), 2) + ' ' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(mm, GETDATE())), 2) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()))
```

Following comments, an example input date would be 21st June 2016 (year = 2016, month = 06, day = 21), for which the desired output would be 21 06 2016.

Comment: Please, show us samples of your data, and what output you require.

Comment: what's wrong with the first one?

Comment: @gofr, not sure it adds anything, but I've included a specific date example.

Comment: @RichBenner, nothing particularly wrong with it other than the fact it's hacky.  Trying to establish whether there was a style value I could use with CONVERT that I was missing.

Comment: The date format you want to use is not an 'official' one (not listed in any date/time related standards), SQL Server has no built-in format to get it. Check the [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function if you are on or above SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @ChrisDisley sure, it's going to be hacky doing this in SQL, I'd try to do this in the presentation layer wherever possible. I think this is going to be your best shot at doing it in SQL though.

Comment: @Pred thanks for the input.  Unfortunately can't use FORMAT as have to support older versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with your first suggestion, seems the most appropriate;

Making some test data;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Dates') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Dates
GO
CREATE TABLE #Dates (OriginalDate datetime)
INSERT INTO #Dates (OriginalDate)
VALUES
('2016-01-01')
,('2016-05-06')
,('2016-08-09')
,('2016-12-25')
```

Query;

```
SELECT
OriginalDate
,REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,OriginalDate,103),'/',' ') NewDate
FROM #Dates
```

Result;

```
OriginalDate                NewDate
2016-01-01 00:00:00.000     01 01 2016
2016-05-06 00:00:00.000     06 05 2016
2016-08-09 00:00:00.000     09 08 2016
2016-12-25 00:00:00.000     25 12 2016
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'll mark as answer on basis I can't see anything better either.  Was just really surprised that it's missing as a standard format.  Must come up quite frequently.

Comment: it's there with the slashes in but not with spaces unfortunately. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The date format `DD MM YYYY` is not an 'official' format (with only spaces and no periods), therefore there is no format code for it in SQL Server.

You can use the workaround, you mentioned in the question or the [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function in SQL Server 2012 or above: `FORMAT(GETDATE(), N'dd MM yyyy')`.

There are other workarounds, but none of them are beautiful, including this contraption: `RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DAY(@date)), 2) + ' ' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MONTH(@date)), 2) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(@date))`

Another option is to create a **CLR function** and use .NET to format dates. CLRs are available since 2005.

You can create a **calendar table** and add a field with the desired format. You can join this table to get the formatted string for each date.

**In general, formatting the result is not the SQL Server's responsibility, move this into the application which is using the data.**

Comment: The application is SQL Server - it's updating a denormalised value in a reporting table as part of a larger batch of SQL.  There's no additional application to update.

Comment: Updating a single field with the formatted date in it (and the date only) or is it concatenated with something else. The part `In general` means, that sometimes you can't avoid to do it outside the SQL Server.